# Python 3 Error with input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to do an SPOJ problem and getting the number of test cases using:

```
tc = int(input())
```

However, I get a "non-zero exit code" error from that line when running my code.  Here's the full code:

```
def is_on_edge(row, col, rows, cols):
    is_top = row == 0
    is_left = col == 0
    is_right = (col == cols - 1)
    is_bottom = (row == rows - 1)
    return is_top or is_left or is_right or is_bottom

tc = int(input())

for i in range(tc):
    rows, cols = map(int, input().split())
    for r in rows:
        for c in cols:
            if is_on_edge(r, c, rows, cols):
                print("*", end="")
            else:
                print(".", end="")
    print("")
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the error has anything to do with *that* line?

Comment: @user2357112 Because the online judge gives me an end of file error from that line

Comment: You'll need to reproduce the error locally and see exactly what sort it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rows, cols = map(int, input().split())
```

makes rows and cols be ints

```
for r in rows:
    for c in cols:
```

tries to iterate ints, which raises an exception.  After changing above to

```
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
```

code runs without exception on Win10, 3.6.